# Get ckeditor object from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

I have a situation where i have to take the CKeditor text from an iframe, in javascript, following some answers to similar problems (but not exactly the sames) i've arrived to get the inner html of the page and what i get is the textarea of the CKeditor.

To get what i've written above i've used this method:
document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.body

Now from here i would like to do one of those two things, but i don't know how or if it's possible:
1) First and more preferable, i would like to parse the body as a CKEDITOR instance, so that i can use the libray methods to get the text inside, is it possible?
2) Second (if the first option is not possible) i would like to navigate more inside but the only way that i have in mind is another getElementsById, but by reading some answer around i've seen that this is not a good practice to do what i need, why?

What's the best practice between the two? (Or if there is another way, what is it?)

Comment: Do you really need to work directly with the iframe? Can't you use the CKEditor API to get the content or the editable host? it's something alike CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable(), but I'm wrtting off the top of my head

Comment: no sadly i knew it, but i have to use an iframe